# Tool for making sure two vector layers are identical?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geometry, qgis-processing

I have to constantly compare new project boundaries with old project boundaries (both are polygon shapefiles) to make sure that both the outside boundaries and the inside segments haven’t changed.

Is there a tool to check whether the two shapefiles are identical? So I don’t have to check each visually.

Comment: Try `"Select by location"` with `'equals'` parameter. BTW what output are you expecting to achieve? And does the same placed object from both layers share the same `'id'`?

Comment: Try "Symmetrical Difference". It creates a layer containing features from both the input and overlay layers but with the overlapping areas between the two layers removed. The attribute table of the symmetrical difference layer contains attributes and fields from both the input and overlay layers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I don’t need an output per se. Just need to confirm the two layers cover the exact same geographical area. No the layers probably won’t have the same ID.     I tried using symmetrical difference but it always seems to leave a line around the outside, even if the layers are identical. so it doesn’t show if the layers are identical

Answer (score 2):

There should be no line around the outside if layers are identical. Simple test with PostGIS shows a match with a theory.

```
select ST_AsText(ST_SymDifference(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 460 500, 560 420, 460 420, 460 500 ))'),
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 460 500, 560 420, 460 420, 460 500 ))')));

"GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY"
```

It is very unlikely that data from different sources matches exactly vertex by vertex and so that coordinates of vertices match till the last digit of double precision floating point numbers. It is not simple at all to analyze the similarity of geometries automatically. See for example http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc15/tech-workshops/tw_313-144.pdf

In your use case it might be good enough to take the area of the geometry from the symmetric difference and decide how big value is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to calculate the WKT representation of each geometry and compare them.

To get the WKT representation, you type the following syntax in the field calculator.

[image]

With Python, you get the values of the 2 geometries and make a comparison with the operator '==' of the following form:

```
first_geometry == second_geometry 

# Result
True or False
```

I can guide you through the python script.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve never used python before so I don’t know much more than where the console is in QGIS  it would be amazing if you could help with that. Also would I be able to include this python script in a pre-made “graphical model”?

Comment: Yes, you can use in the graphical model the field calculator and the advanced field calculator Python.